# Referencing .net framework assemblies in .net core 2 that rely on the ConfigurationManager

Tags: asp.net, configuration, .net-core-2.0

We have some legacy 4.5.2 class libraries that make common use of `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]`

Is it possible to reference these within a .net core 2 application so that the config is correctly patched up under the hood? 
I.e. the old calls into `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]` correctly read the config, either from json or xml, but within the .netcore2 app.

If I port the `keys` of question to appSettings.json then the call into `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` always returns null.

An example would be:

```
{
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "Console": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    }
},
"appSettings": {"test": "bo"},
"test": "hi"
}
```

And then:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"] , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appSettings:test"] };
}
```

Will display:

```
["value1","value2",null,null]
```

Comment: I accept this isn't the way config _should_ be handled in .netcore2 however was trying to gauge how much of the legacy code base would work without alteration.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Nope, we have yet to make the move to .net core for these projects.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258251/net-core-2-0-appsettings-with-net-full-framework-using-configurationmanager

Comment: @ATerry Wouldn't that require the .NET 4.5.2 project to be upgraded to .NET 4.6.1 as 4.5.x is not compatible with .NET Core/Standard 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setup you are looking for is possible and the settings can be kept as-is in app.config.

I have a .NET 4.5.2 class library "MyLibrary" and a .NET Core 2.0 web application "WebApp" referencing the full .NET framework 4.6.1.

**MyLibrary**

- has an assembly reference to `System.Configuration`
- has a `class Foo` which reads an appsetting with key `foo`

**WebApp**

- has a project reference to MyLibrary
- has an assembly reference to `System.Configuration`
- has an `app.config` file containing the `appSettings` section. (`App.config` is by default present in a .NET Core 2.0 web application project.)
- uses in instance of `Foo`, calls its `GetSomething` method by which the value `bar` gets assigned to the variable `something`.

All other files and settings are the default ones. Here below are the ones mentioned above.

---

## MyLibrary project

.NET 4.5.2

**Foo.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace PFX
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public String GetSomething()
        {
            String r = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["foo"];
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

---

## WebApp project

.NET Core 2.0.1 referencing full .NET framework 4.6.1.

**WebApp.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">    
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="2.0.4" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
     </ItemGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj" />
     </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    </ItemGroup>    
</Project>
```

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
       <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="foo" value="bar"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace WebApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PFX.Foo foo = new PFX.Foo();
            String someting = foo.GetSomething(); // bar

            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(String[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```